# Why "git pull" is updated files when implemented immediately after checking out a remote branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch, git-pull, git-checkout

I use IntellijIDEA,

1. At the branches view( right bottom corner) I select  a brunch from remote branches which I have never checked out before ( I didn't even knew it's name before read at my Jira task )
2. Clicked on it
3. Checkout As...
4. Left the original name ( the same as remote name)
5. OK

I I wish I got an up to date branch ( isn't it reasonably?) but when I immediately select Git -> pull, I got **588 files updated in 627 commits** at this branch?

Please explain what is the logic? Isn't it reasonably to expect to get an up to date branch when checkout and expect pull will say "everything is up to date" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies to the fact that those branches are lastly updated the last time you `git pull -all`.

For example, If you clone a project, those branches come with the latest commits (up to date). But if you don't `git pull --all` for some time then those branches aren't going to be updated. In that case your branches do not contain the last updates and so you have to `git pull -all` in order to update them.

In sum up, the branches are lastly updated from the time you cloned the project or the last time you `git pull -all`, but they are not automatically updated.

If there are new branches added to the remote then you have to fetch them first with `git fetch --all`.

Comment: Ok, what if the specific remote branch didn't even exist when I did  "git pull origin master" last time? Should I even not to see it in the list? How to check it out then?

Comment: You shouldn't. If a branch was pushed after the last time you pulled from origin master, you shouldn`t be able too checkout out them. You have to pull the changes first and then checkout the newly added bracnhes.

Comment: pull the changes exact on master but not on any branch else? Is the master branch is special one which updates not only itself but all meta information about other branches?

Comment: All you need to do is a `fetch`. A `pull` does a fetch and merge. Maybe you don't want to merge. `git fetch --all`

Comment: Ok, fetch exact on master but not on any branch else? Is the master branch is special one which updates not only itself but all meta information about other branches?

Comment: `git fetch` will get updated references for all branches. The `--all` option means all branches on all remotes.

Comment: `--all` is rarely useful: it only means *all remotes*.  (It does not change which *branches* come from those remotes; that's controlled by the refspec you set, or didn't set, for each remote.)